# Problem with kivy installation

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, python

I'm trying to install the `kivy` framework. But first I need to install these packages:

```
python-setuptools python-pygame python-opengl python-gst0.10 python-enchant gstreamer0.10-plugins-good python-dev build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev cython
```

The problem I have is with `libgles2-mesa-dev`. When I try to install it I get the following:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgles2-mesa-dev : Depends: libgles2-mesa (= 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6)
                     Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I already reinstalled Ubuntu (I'm using Ubuntu 12.04), because the last time I tried to install `libgles2-mesa-dev` I installed `ligbles2-mesa` and `libegl1-mesa-dev`, something went wrong and I broke `xserver`.

What do I need to do in order to install it properly?

Is there something i'm doing wrong?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems the problem is solved. What i did whas instsall `libgles-mesa-dev-lts-raring` instead. I do not know if this is the proper solution, but it's working now.