# How do I install kivy?

Tags: software-installation

I was trying to install Kivy (by following the instructions [here](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html)). I downloaded and installed all packages where the installation process went through without giving me any errors.

However, when later I enter below command;

```
sudo easy_install kivy
```

It looked like it was going to work but it ends with an error by displaying following lines, which I don't comprehend:

```
Detected compiler is unix
/tmp/easy_install-BtOA_u/Kivy-1.8.0/kivy/graphics/texture.c:8:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
#include "pyconfig.h"
                  ^
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I saw a similar question asked as;
  [Problem with kivy installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395058/problem-with-kivy-installation). However, this didn't work for me though the question suggests installing `libgles-mesa-dev-lts-raring` which I did as below;

```
sudo apt-get install libgles-mesa-dev-lts-raring
```

which then gave below;

```
E: Unable to locate package libgles-mesa-dev-lts-raring
```

(sorry for being so specific and perhaps obvious, but I'm in the early stage of learning my way around linux).

This user was running Ubuntu 12.04, and most other questions related to this I've seen came from people with a different release from mine, which has led me to believe that that is the reason why the suggestions to those didn't solve my problem.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: ... and where does that install the kivy examples?

Answer (score 5):

Try the below commands on the terminal to install `kivy` on **Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04**,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-kivy
```

Answer (score 2):

First add one of the PPA's -

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy` - stable builds 
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy-daily` - nightly builds
next,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-kivy
```

The download will be approx. of 35 mb
For optional examples,

```
sudo apt-get install python-kivy-examples
```

Thats all you need for installation of kivy on ubuntu.
For more information on installation refer to this [page](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html)

Comment: Can you also tell us how to access the examples?

Comment: Examples are in `/usr/share/kivy-examples`

Comment: I see them in /usr/share/kivi-examples/ ...

Answer (score 0):

you can also go with git...with git you can use kivy with both python2.x or python3.x.
**first, install dependencies:**
if you are installing for "python3" then use "pip3"
`sudo pip install cython pygments docutils`
**now add the repo form git**
`git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy`
`cd kivy`
**installation**
if you want kivy for "python3" this instead of python type "python3"
`python setup.py build`
`sudo python setup.py install`

For more on installing kivy see the [users guide.](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-linux.html)